# return rows only if value of 3 columns is same

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a sql in the below format:

```
with row_source as (select ........)
select a,b,c,x,y,z
```

I need to add a query on top of this such that it returns only rows when the values of the columns x,y,z are same.

Can you please suggest.Thanks.

Comment: `where x = y and y = z`?

Comment: Does "same" include all nulls?

Comment: 'same' does not include null...there will always be some value.

Comment: how to get the rows where x,y,z columns are not matching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could generate an additional column m first using `case when` (e.g., if x=y=z then assign 1 else assign 0). Subsequently when you select rows from the table you add `where m = 1`.